# VIM: Unable to uninstall Latex-Box plugin with Vimball

Tags: vim

According to documentation, vimball uninstall should be a very simple process of typing in :RmVimball LatexBox

However, I get the error message
***vimball*** (RmVimball) unable to find  in .VimballRecord

I'm pretty sure I'm typing in the right prompt because LatexBox.vmb is the file I ran :so % on to install the plugin.

The Vimball documentation (http://www.cs.csubak.edu/docs/vim/pi_vimball.html) states:

*:RmVimball removes all files generated by the specified vimball
    (but not any directories it may have made).  One may choose a path
    for de-installation, too (see |'runtimepath'|); otherwise, the
    default is the first existing directory on the |'runtimepath'|.*

And indeed my .VimballRecord exists in the first existing directory of the output when I type in :echo &runtimepath . I opened up the .VimballRecord and it says

LatexBox.vmb: call delete('C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles/ftplugin/tex_LatexBox.vim')|  ...

which seems to confirm that LatexBox is the correct plugin name. I'm very confused where the error is coming from. Otherwise -- How can I remove this plugin manually? (I'm concerned that going through and deleting files in the ftplugin folder is not thorough)

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall a vim plugin is really easy, because there're no hidden stuff.

- Go into `C:\Program Files\vim\vimfiles`(depending on your system)
- Find out all files about `LatexBox`
- Delete them.

---

Make a backup of `vimfiles` folder before deleting files.
If something goes wrong, you have a change to recover.

---

#### Update:

Answer you question about `:helptags` command:

When you install a plugin, it may contains help files(for example `latexbox.txt`).
It was often install in `C:\Program Files\vim\vimfiles\doc` directory (I will call it `doc` from now).
This direcotry may contains other help files for other plugins.

Notice there's a `tags` file in this `doc` directory. The `tags` file is used for jumping to location when you press <kbd>Ctrl-]</kbd> on a word.

Don't worry if `doc\tags` not exist.
You can use `:helptags C:\Program Files\vim\vimfiles\doc` to generate it.

When you install a plugin via vimball (which is just a vimscript to help you creating files/directories),
The vimball will create `latexbox.txt` in `doc` directory,
and run `:helptags` command to update the `tags` file  automatically.

So, when you manually delete `doc\latexbox.txt`,
the `tags` file still contains infomatation about `latexbox.txt`.
Just run `:helptags path\you\want\to\sync` command again to get `doc\tags` synchronised.

Comment: Thank you! I read something about :helptags on another post which worried me -- would simply deleting files leave behind "helptags"? (I'm not so clear on what they are)

Comment: @Lucy See my update. Don't worry. Even you leave behind `helptags`, nothing breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Been there. The problem is that Vimball version (v31) that comes packaged with Vim is obsolete and does not support .vmb files. Check [1](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1502) for the latest Vimball version and you will be alright.